# Check if variable either nil or satisfies some condition

Tags: swift

Is this approach swiftly enough? (there is something I don't like in it) :

```
guard index ?? 1 > 0 else { ...
```

Or one more example:

```
while i < index ?? i + 1 {
    ...
    i += 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that:

```
guard index ?? 1 > 0 else { ...
```

is concise, but it doesn't seem right because you have to choose a default value just to make the condition work, and it seems like a bit of a kludge.

You can write it exactly as you describe:

```
guard index == nil || index! > 0 { ...
```

That works and is safe because the `||` statement short circuits and prevents the force unwrap from crashing, but it does still have a force unwrap which some tools like SwiftLint flag as an issue.

A third alternative is to use the *optional* form of `map`:

```
guard index.map({ $0 > 0 }) ?? true { ...
```

Here, the closure will only be executed if `index` has a value, otherwise it will return `nil`.  The `??` is then used to provide the desired result of `true` for the `nil` case.  It has the advantage of not using a force unwrap or a kludge value, but it is a bit difficult to read.

---

Likewise for your second example, your choices are:

Choose a default value that makes it work:

```
while i < index ?? i + 1 { ...
```

Check for `nil` and then safely force unwrap:

```
while index == nil || i < index! { ...
```

Use `map` and `??`:

```
while index.map({ i < $0 }) ?? true { ...
```

---

Frankly, I like the explicit check for `nil` and safe force unwrap because it precisely conveys your intention.

**Note:**  In the case of an equals comparison, you can skip the force unwrap.  So

```
if index ?? 7 == 7 { ...
```

can be written as:

```
if index == nil || index == 7 { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if variable == nil {
    //do something
} else if variable == (your condition) {
    //do something
}
```

is that what you wanted?

Comment: No. If variable == nill || variable! == (your condition) { do something }